# Regex filter string number and number not working

Tags: c#, .net, regex, preg-match

I am trying to extract a string in this format **"[\r\n  \"MG480612230220150018\"\r\n]"** using regex, i am trying to match number and alphabet with a min length of 5 character but it is not working, therefore i can guarantee i will extract this data (**MG480612230220150018**)

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,}$");
        Match match = regex.Match(availability.Id.ToString());
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var myid = match.Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[a-z\d]{5,}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

---

Regex Explanantion:

```
[a-z\d]{5,}

Options: Case insensitive

Match a single character present in the list below «[a-z\d]{5,}»
   Between 5 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{5,}»
   A character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive) «a-z»
   A “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d»
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are matching at the beginning and end of string. As you say, the input string is longer `[\r\n \"MG480612230220150018\"\r\n]`. So, you need to remove the anchors:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,}");
```

And you will get the match (`MG480612230220150018`).

Have a look at the [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B0-9a-zA-Z%5D%7B5%2C%7D&i=%5B%0D%0A%20%22MG480612230220150018%22%0D%0A%5D).

As an alternative, in C#, I would use Unicode classes to match characters:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\p{N}\p{L}]{5,}");
```

`\p{N}` stands for a Unicode number, and `\p{L}` for any Unicode letter, case-insensitive.

Comment: @Kachou: I understand you can select any answer as accepted, but I would accept the correct answer provided first. Also, Pedro's regex is next to equivalent to mine. Also note, that `[0-9]` will match the numbers from 0 to 9 strictly, and `\d` will match all digits from all scripts in C#. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html. So, it is not equivalent to what you have in your original regex. I only suggested a Unicode-compatible variant for you to choose from. And finally, `[a-zA-Z]` does not require `IgnoreCase` option.